# please suggest design pattern

Tags: design-patterns

I am trying to find out, what pattern will be the best to use in following scenario.

I have different types of Data representation for user. User can choose , how data will be rendered on screen.

1. List item
2. Drop Down List
3. Radio Buttons List
4. Check Boxes etc..

I know , that Abstract factory , or factory method will suite here. But is there any way to get rid of following:

```
If (SomeType == SomeTypes.DropDown)
 {
    return new DropDownClass();
 }
```

Is there any way to do it more abstractive ?

Comment: at some point, even in a factory, you have to determine what to return...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a List for SimpleFactories and ask each in turn if it can handle the Type and if so let it create the component.

It would look like this:

```
interface SimpleFactory{
    boolean canHandle(SomeType type);
    Component create()
}

class Factory{
    List<SimpleFactory) factories = ....

Component create(SomeType type){
    for(f : factories)
        if (f.canHandle(type) return f.create()
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in .Net I regularly use a combination of generics, inheritance and polymorphism to determine the handler for a specific request during run-time.

It all is very easy when you use something like described in [this](http://elegantcode.com/2009/12/18/advanced-unity-connecting-implementations-to-open-generic-types/) post